# How to have variables of scores

Tags: c, cs50

I have a question, how can I get a variable of scores from user and take that variable to divide to get the average number, I saw I could change line 19, the scores[] to something and the number to divide, can anyone show me how to do it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
int n = get_int("How many scores you have? ");
int score[n];
  for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    score[i] = get_int("Score: ");
  }
printf("Average: %.2f\n", (score[n] + score[n]+ score[n]) / 3.0);
}
```

Comment: An array of `n` elements have indexes from `0` to `n - 1`, as you seem to already know. Then think about what happens if you use `n` itself as an index (in `score[n]`). It will be *out of bounds*. If you want to calculate the average of the three first elements of `score` you need to use the tree first elements with the proper indexes: `score[0]`, `score[1]`, and `score[2]`. If you want the average of all elements from the array, you need a loop to calculate the sum, and then divide by `n`.

Comment: And unless you want to use the scores later, you don't actually need an array. All you need is a `sum` (initialized to `0`), and then in your existing loop add the input to `sum` (like `sum += get_int(...)`). Then divide `sum` with `(double) n` to get the average.

Comment: Google _rubber duck debugging_. This is no joke.

Answer (score 2):

declare `int i` before the first loop make another loop to add up all the scores and divide at the end by `i` (the number of scores) to get the average.
like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("How many scores you have? ");
    int score[n];
    double average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        score[i] = get_int("Score: ");
        average+=score[i] // if you just need the average you can delete the line int score[n] and the line above and change score[i] to get_int("Score: "); 
    }
    average = average / n;
    printf("Average: %.2f\n", average);
}
```

Comment: This does not help. `score[n]` is still out of bounds access and without summing up all the numbers you will not get a proper average. Also, after the loop `i` will always be same as `n`.

Comment: you're right I didn't thought of that I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: update is uploaded!

Comment: I tested it and it works just fine

Comment: Now it is nearly correct. You don't initialize `average=0`. Also there is no need to use a second loop as you can do that in the first one. And no need to move definition of `i` out of the loop as you can use `n` instead.

Comment: "Works just fine" or "Works on my machine" is just one possible variant of undefined behaviour.

Comment: `int n = get_int("");  int score[n];` I thought this doesn't work, does it?

Comment: @zibidigonzales this is called a "Variable Length Array" (VLA) and was introduced in C99. It is optional on later versions. Of course you should keep an eye on stack usage...

Comment: now my answer should be fine!

Comment: the VLA isn't "really" an VLA since ist doesn't change anymore

Comment: tho you could change `int n` to `const int n`

Comment: It is variable but not dynamic

Comment: Yes that's true